# The $@ variable is not working in a for loop, trying to iterate through a users list

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, for, programming

**PROBLEM:**

I can't get the `$@` variable to do what I want in a for loop, the loop only sends one name into the file while looping, it should loop through all the arguments and write them to the file `USERS.txt` each on its own line.

Here is the file:

```
something78
something79
something7
dagny
oli
bjarni
toti
stefan_hlynur
jessie
```

---

Here is the test code:

```
#!/bin/bash

prepare_USERS()
{
    /usr/bin/awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 { print $1 }' /etc/passwd > USERS.txt
    /bin/chmod 777 USERS.txt
    echo "$@"
    for user in "$@"
    do
        echo $user
        echo "$user" >> USERS.txt || echo "writing to USERS.txt failed"; exit 127
    done
}

prepare_USERS "$@"

#for user in "$@"
#do
#    echo "$user" >> USERS.txt
#done

for user in USERS.txt
do
    printf "%s" $user
done
```

Here are the arguments I pass:

```
./somethingDELETEme.sh jessie henry allison jason
```

**CURRENT output:**

```
$./somethingDELETEme.sh jessie henry allison jason
jessie henry allison jason
jessie
```

**EXPECTED output:**

The loop loops through all names from the argument list and writes it to the file `USERS.txt`.

**QUESTION:**

*I have used this variable (`$@`) before and never had this problem.*

Why is the loop not iterating through all names in the argument list (`$@`) and how is the right way coding this?

**HERE IS THE REAL CODE:**

```
prepare_USERS()
{
    checkIfUser
    /usr/bin/awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 { print $1 }' /etc/passwd > "$CURRENTDIR"/USERS.txt

    /bin/chmod 777 "CURRENTDIR"/USERS.txt
    for user in "$@"
    do
        echo "$user" >> "CURRENTDIR"/USERS.txt || echo "writing to USERS.txt failed"; exit 127
    done
}
```

Comment: Pls be aware that mode 777 (= including execute permission) on a pure data file is unnecessary and may be a security risc. Make up your mind WHO should write that file, and WHO should read it. 600 or 640 may be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the incorrect usage of `exit 127` in your for loop, which is exiting after the first for-loop iteration. You need to group the `echo` statement and the `exit` as a compound block under `{..}` to prevent this.

```
echo "$user" >> USERS.txt || { echo "writing to USERS.txt failed"; exit 127; }
```

Without this grouping what happens is the `||` defined applies *only* for the `echo` command and *always* run the `exit` command no matter if re-direction to file passed or failed because you have a command separator `;` defined there.

Now with the compound grouping enabled, the entire set of actions inside `{..}` is treated as one block and both of them are executed if the write action to `USERS.txt` fails.

Comment: Why isn't this a problem in my code: `/bin/chmod 644 "$HOME/.bashrc" || echo "chmod failed"; exit 127`

Comment: It isn't a problem, it will run the `exit` command always, the scope of `||` ends with the `echo "chmod failed"`. Since you have `;` after that, calling `exit` would return from function/terminal or script depending on where you run it

Comment: Or write it as an `if` statement: `if ! echo "$user" >> USERS.txt; then echo "failed..."; exit 127; fi` The effect is the same, but some might find the `if` clearer to read.